# Docker swarm node unable to detect service from another host in swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, dask, docker-swarm-mode, dask-distributed

My goal is to set up a docker swarm on a group of 3 linux (ubuntu) physical workstations and run a [dask](https://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) cluster on that.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
```

I am able to init the docker swarm and add all of the machines to the swarm.

```
cordoba$ docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME    STATUS    AVAILABILITY MANAGER STATUS
j8k3hm87w1vxizfv7f1bu3nfg     box1        Ready     Active              
twg112y4m5tkeyi5s5vtlgrap     box2        Ready     Active              
upkr459m75au0vnq64v5k5euh *   box3        Ready     Active              Leader
```

I then run `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml dask-cluster` on the Leader box.

Here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"

services:

  dscheduler:
    image: richardbrks/dask-cluster
    ports:
     - "8786:8786"
     - "9786:9786"
     - "8787:8787"
    command: dask-scheduler
    networks:
      - distributed
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

  dworker:
    image: richardbrks/dask-cluster
    command: dask-worker dscheduler:8786
    environment:
      - "affinity:container!=dworker*"
    networks:
      - distributed
    depends_on:
      - dscheduler
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

networks:
  distributed:
```

and here is `richardbrks/dask-cluster`:

```
# Official python base image
FROM python:2.7    
# update apt-repository
RUN apt-get update
# only install enough library to run dask on a cluster (with monitoring)
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir \
    psutil \
    dask[complete]==0.15.2 \
    bokeh
```

When I deploy the swarm, the `dworker` nodes that are not on the same machine as `dscheduler`
does not know what `dscheduler` is. I ssh'd into one of these nodes and looked in env,
and `dscheduler` was not there. I also tried to ping `dscheduler`, and got "ping: unknown host".

I thought docker was supposed to provide an internal dns based for service discovery
so that calling `dscheduler` will take me to the address of the `dschedler` node.

Is there some set up to my computers that I am missing? or are any of my files missing something?

All of this code is also located in https://github.com/MentalMasochist/dask-swarm

Comment: Could you please describe how you try to access the other service? Do you do in inside the dworker container?

Comment: @herm Yes. I ssh into the computer where the `dworker` node is being ran, I use `docker ps` to get the id of the container running, and then I type `docker exec -ti <docker id> /bin/bash` to enter into the node. That is where I'm attempting to ping `dscheduler`.

Comment: You are confusing terms. A node in a swarm is a computer. with docker exec you enter a container and not a node. You used the wrong names but did the right thing :)

Comment: I checked and your setup works fine and I could telnet from worker to scheduler on different machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with dask or docker swarm. The problem was bad router firmware. After I went back to a prior version of the router firmware, the cluster worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1429) in swarm:

> Because of some networking limitations (I think related to virtual
>   IPs), the ping tool will not work with overlay networking. Are you
>   service names resolvable with other tools like dig?

Personally I could always connect from one service to the other using curl. Your setup seems correct and your services should be able to communicate.

---

FYI depends on is not supported in swarm

---

Update 2: I think you are not using the port. Servicename is no replacement for the port. You need to use the port as the container knows it internally.

Comment: I installed and ran dig inside the container, but got a `NXDOMAIN` error, which means it couldn't find the host. Your issue link showed some other possible reasons for not being able to connect other services on other hosts. I will read though the issue and see if any of their suggestions solve me problem.  Also, Thanks for informing me about `depends_on`.

Comment: Tarun Lalwani confirmed that your compose file is correct. What is the exact command you use to connect the containers? For curl it would be:
curl http://dscheduler:8786/path

Comment: The container dworker should connect to dscheduler from the command `dask-worker dscheduler:8786` from the compose file where `dscheduler` should be the ip of the scheduler and 8786 is the port. Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes. Can you reach the other machine by IP? maybe the ports are not open or a firewall is intervening.

Comment: I am able to ping the master node machine from the worker node and from the container in the worker node.

Comment: I have no idea why this won't work for you. I'm sorry

Comment: Also, from the worker node (not in the container though), netcat is able to connect to the following ports on the master node: 2377(tcp), 7946(tcp), 7946(udp) and 4789(udp).

Comment: what about 8786? Since you publish this port (8786:8786) it should also be reachable

Comment: I think I found something. When I am inside the container on the worker node, I get the following error: `root@adc78cf2c38d:/# netcat -vz cordoba.<company>.com 8786
DNS fwd/rev mismatch: cordoba.<company>.com != <ip-address>-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net
cordoba.company.com [<ip-address>] 8786 (?) open` Values with <> around them are me anonymizing the output.

Comment: Your network seems to be your problem and not docker swarm

Comment: Found the problem: The firmware in our office's router had a bug. Once I went back to a prior firmware version, everything worked fine. @herm: thanks for the help!